# eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker v4.17.37 widget not loading using common.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, commonjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Apologies if this seems like I'm missing something very obvious.
(I'm using an app built with npm and backbone)
I am trying to load my datetimepicker module using common.js

```
datetimepicker = require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker')
```

When I go to add a datetimepicker in my app, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

When I look in my debugger I can see the module is not getting loaded.
It has been installed in my node modules folder. I'm just wondering can anyone spot anything obvious I could be missing.
I have imported moment and jquery as they are listed dependencies.
They are imported/loaded before the datetimepicker.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with commonjs, but have you defined `'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker` as the path to actual .js file somewhere..?

Comment: yes, as far as I know. npm will automatically check the node_modules folder for eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker module once I have added

datetimepicker = require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker')

it will check a module called eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker exists and if so it will then check for a package.json file for the module.

Where there should be some reference on how to access the js file.
Thanks for the reply TJ

Comment: @tonyMcMister how did you solve did? I have [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604288/datetimepicker-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.datetimepicker = require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');
```

Also be sure that you load moment.js which required for this library