# $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and want to use [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). In my *webpack config* I use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) to get "jquery module".

In my code I get error `$(...).datetimepicker is not a function` when I call `$('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker` function. I don't why `$` variable doesn't contain `datetimepicker` function, which should be defined in `var datetimepicker = require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');`

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
console.log("target event is " + TARGET);

var common = {
  cache: true,
  debug: true,
  entry: './src/script/index.jsx',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js[x]?$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css']
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass']
    }, {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less']
    }, {
      test: /\.woff$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=[path][name].[ext]"
    }, {
      test: /\.woff2$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=[path][name].[ext]"
    }, {
      test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/,
      loader: "file-loader"
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  postcss: function() {
    return [autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 3 versions']
    })];
  }
};

if (TARGET === 'dev' || !TARGET) {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
    },
    output: {
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
    },
    plugins: [
      new NpmInstallPlugin({
        save: true // --save
      })
    ]
  });
}
```

**index.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var bootstrapStyle = require("../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");

var datetimepicker = require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');

class DateTimePicker extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
              inline: true,
              sideBySide: true
          });
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="wrapper">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                            <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <DateTimePicker/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-bootstrap-datetimepicker",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "webpack-bootstrap-datetimepicker",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --port 8090"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "less": "^2.6.0",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "postcss": "^5.0.15",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.7.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.15.35"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well do you have `datetimepicker.js` included?

Comment: Yes, I do. Solution is [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/1431)

Comment: You have to add 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker' in your entry as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution is in [pull request](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/1431) on Github.

Answer (score 5):

One way of making the changes for $.fn persistent (without editing the source) is to use `expose` plugin in combination with `imports`:

```
module : {
    loaders : [
            {
                test : /jquery/,
                loader : 'expose-loader?$!expose?jQuery'
            },
            {
                test : /eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/,
                loader : 'imports-loader?define=>false,exports=>false,moment=moment'
            }]
}
```

What exactly do these arguments for imorts loader do?

When you look at the source, it starts with

```
'use strict';
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD is used - Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery', 'moment'], factory);
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'), require('moment'));
```

and then proceeds

```
} else {
// Neither AMD nor CommonJS used. Use global variables.
```

This part `define=>false,exports=>false` prepends a piece of JavaScript that sets both `define` and `exports` (inside wrapped module definition) to `false`, allowing it to proceed to the "use the globals" part, which is exactly what we want. `moment=moment` tells it to set a variable `moment` equal to `require('moment')`, now when the datepicker tries to resolve the libraries from the globals, it reaches to the `var moment=...` definition. If you plan to include `moment` from the globals (not as npm dependency), you should omit this argument.

Comment: What does it mean `exports=>false,moment=moment` part in import loader?

Answer (score 5):

Found a simpler solution here: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1319

The solution:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // Force all modules to use the same jquery version.
            'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/src/jquery')
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is still working in 2020. Is there any modern solution?

Answer (score -1):

you need to check #datetimepicker12 is correct or not it exist to your browser or not.press F12 and press ctrl+F and find id exist.
And the other way any error jquery file missing espacially datetime picker js file  on your page you get error 404 about that file.put that file at the top all js files hope your problem will be solve

Comment: file not found on the page 404 error occurred then put datetimepicker.js file at the top of you all js files may be it solved

Comment: I don't get a 404 error and datetimepicker.js code is included by webpack. Please read my question.